# Why do I keep getting a 500 internal server error from my python code?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, python-3.x, cgi

I'm working on a code that is supposed to be a search engine for marvel characters, however, my python section is returning a 500 error when it's called by the javascript. I know the javascript works because I tested it using a sample python script that the professor gave us, but I don't know why my code isn't working. It's supposed to return a string with commas separating the different values (the name of the character and a link to their wiki). The code works when I change the cgi.FieldStorage() to a simple input and just run it by itself, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# namelookup.py - Program to display name statistics
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi;
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
filePath="/home/class/SoftDev/namedata/"

def readfile(filename):
  infile=open(filename,mode='r')
  array=[]
  for line in infile:
    templine=line
    array.append(templine.split(','))
  infile.close()
  return array[::-1]

def removePunctuation(s):
  #Remove all punctuation from a string
  import string
  for c in string.punctuation:
    s= s.replace(c,"")
  return s

def createNameIndex(array):
  #creates an index of every name and the number of the lines tha   have that number on it
  index={}
  arraylen=len(array)
  for x in range(arraylen):
    allnames=removePunctuation(array[x][1]).lower().split(' ')
    #catalogs each name, so "Peter Parker" will also appear wheyou    search for just Peter or Parker. This has an addebenefit in    that it allows the program to determine answermore relevant to    the search, see the sortrelevancy function
    for name in allnames:
      if not name in index:
        index[name]=[x]
      else:
        index[name].append(x)
  return index

def createYearIndex(array):
  #creates an index the same as the name index, except with years  instead of names
  index={}
  arraylen=len(array)
  for x in range(arraylen):
    year=array[x][12][0:4]
    if year in index:
      index[year].append(x)
    else:
      index[year]=[x]
  return index


def searchFor(term,nameindex,yearindex):
  #searches the indexes for the desired term, keeping track oeach    row that comes  back, including duplicates, which wilbe used by    sortRelevancy
  allterms=term.split()
  allterms.append(term)
  allterms.append(term.replace(" ",''))
  results=[]
  for word in allterms:
    if word in nameindex:
      for number in nameindex[word]:
        results.append(number)
    if word in yearindex:
      for number in yearindex[word]:
        results.append(number)
  return results


def print_header():
    print ("""Content-type: text/html\n""")

def sortRelevancy(numberlist):
  #counts the number of times that each answer has appeared, then  sorts them in that order so that the name that appeared thmost    times is at the top.
  sortednumbers={}
  for number in numberlist:
    if not number in sortednumbers:
      sortednumbers[number]=1
    else:
      sortednumbers[number]=sortednumbers[number]+1
  finallist=sorted(sortednumbers.items(), key=lambda kv:(kv[1], [0])   )
  finallist= finallist[::-1]
  return finallist[0:10] # to prevent too many results, only th10    most relevant are shown

def main():
  #main function, combines all the above part and supplies the  interface for the user
  filename=readfile ('/home/class/SoftDev/marvel/marvel-wikia-data.csv')
  marvelindex=createNameIndex(filename)
  yearindex=createYearIndex(filename)
  form = cgi.FieldStorage()
  searchforme=removePunctuation(form.getvalue("name").lower())
  resultlist=searchFor(searchforme,marvelindex,yearindex)
  listicle=sortRelevancy(resultlist)
  results=""
  print_header()
  if listicle==[]:
    print("No results found.")
  else:
    for x in listicle:
        results+=filename[x[0]][1]+", "+filename[x[0]][2]+", "
  print(results)


main()
```

Comment: Try to give proper file permission to your cgi script and then restart the server and run it @wasianpower

Comment: You should also use list and dictionary comprehension instead of nested loops.

Comment: Did you check your webserver's error_log?

Comment: @amrs-tech unfortunately I don't have control over the server, I'm running it off of my school's CS department server.

Comment: @KlausD. I went over the error log with my professor, I can't remember exactly what it said but my prof said that he couldn't glean anything useful from it

Comment: @wasianpower In my case, I faced such situation twice or thrice and the solutions were like either **"The .py handler wasn't added to the AddHandler of cgi scripts in Apache httpd.conf file"** or **"The python cgi file inside cgi-bin folder didn't have some file permission, when I granted it worked"**. These were in my local Apache server. I am not sure what could be the problem in your case.